# Getting an undefined error in react native while using react-native-draggable-flatlist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, draggable

I am trying to create a draggable to do list using [react-native-draggable-flatlist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-draggable-flatlist) module. But I am getting a this error:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function, js engine: hermes

This is my code:

```
  const Todos = () => {
  const [unfinishedTodos, setUnfinishedTodos] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  function loadData() {
    firestore()
      .collection('todos')
      .orderBy('priority', 'desc')
      .get()
      .then(snap => {
        setLoading(true);
        let unfinished = [];
        snap.docs.map(each => {
          let eachdict = {
            id: each.id,
            taskName: each.get('taskName'),
            taskDesc: each.get('taskDesc'),
            priority: each.get('priority'),
            finished: each.get('finished'),
            time: each.get('time'),
            index: each.get('index'),
            timeType: each.get('timeType'),
          };
            unfinished.push(eachdict);
        });
        setUnfinishedTodos(
          unfinished.sort((a, b) => {
            return a.index - b.index;
          }),
        );
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.message);
      });
  }
           

 return( 
      <DraggableFlatList data={unfinishedTodos} renderItem={({item, index, drag, isActive}) => {
   return (
      <Text>{item.taskName}</Text>
)}}                     
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => `${item.id}`}
    onDragEnd={({data}) => console.log(data)} />
   )}
```

What am I doing wrong or which part of the code has to be replaced?

Comment: Any success? Having the same issue

Comment: Yeah I downgraded to a previous version and it works flawlessly now.. @checklist refer to this https://github.com/computerjazz/react-native-draggable-flatlist/issues/326

Comment: I noticed that my crash was when using: 
getItemLayout={(_data, index) => {
   const itemHeight = 57
    return {        index,     length: itemHeight,    offset: index * itemHeight,   } }}
When commenting it out, it works again. Not sure why. Maybe the developer can help. Downgrading is not really an option for us.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `setLoading`? Maybe it's just that.

```js
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
```

Comment: No i fixed that..thats not the issue...I even tried installing and reinstalling that module back...the issue still persists

Comment: One more thought. Shouldnt `firestore()` be `firebase.firestore()`? What is the firestore function you are calling? My guess is that `firestore()` is undefined.

Comment: Actually I thought the same so I tried exactly the example provided in the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-draggable-flatlist) but I am still getting the same error

Comment: Can you update the question with the contents of the entire file, including the imorts?